# Couchbase value rounding issue?

Tags: c#, json, open-source, rounding, couchbase

When I try to save json in Couchbase Document it will rounding value by default?

This is the Json I'm try to save

```
 {"GUDeviceID": "15091920083214800501",  "GUProductID": 15091218260779201}
```

After save, the couch document shows like this

```
 {"GUDeviceID": "15091920083214800501",  "GUProductID": 15091218260779200}
```

- `GUProductID` Rounding 15091218260779201 = > 15091218260779200
- When I retrieve data using Couchbase.dll (C#) it will return `15091218260779200` as `GUProductID`

Please help me to solve this, Thanks

Comment: something isn't right here: you're saying that your GUProductID is decimal, but in the example you given its not (15091218260779201 is not decimal).

Comment: This is the Answer :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532186/why-couchbase-round-numeric-values-in-a-json-document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `get` function in Couchbase dll. It will return correct value without rounding. This issue occurred when javascript rounding the decimal value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea: save it as text, not as a number. Just wrap the value with quotes.